# Looking for title/author of scifi/fantasy novel - sole female Mage in world where all other mages are male

Tags: story-identification, magic

I read a book over a decade ago and want to read it again but I don't remember the title or the author.

What I remember about it:

A woman crash lands on a foreign planet, finds her way to a place where they train mages. She calls magic 'ler'. Only men are mages on this world. They train her anyway and then travels with her teacher and another student to take a test of some kind to determine her level of power. These levels of power are denoted by unremovable metal rings around the mages neck. The more rings the greater the power.

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/750527.Nameless_Magery?

Comment: Not the answer to the question by Pratchett's *Equal Rites* matches the title (at least allowing that mages and witches are different categories, which the story in effect does)..

Comment: That's it!!!!! Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: "scoff/fantasy novel" - is this a subgenre I haven't heard of, or did you have "scifi" autocompleting to "scoff"? :-)

Comment: Don't forget to click the "accepted" button.

Answer (score 5):

This is [Nameless Magery](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/750527.Nameless_Magery) by Delia Marshall Turner.

---

**Magic is called Her (not Ler)**

> *Everything I called "Her" was "magic" to these people. Have you any
>   idea how blind, malicious, and dangerous the universe looks when
>   everything is caused by a thing called magic?*

**Mages wear unbreakable rings around their necks**

> *One dreary late winter day, with rain and wind spraying sidewise through his study window, I asked him, "Simon, what are those necklaces you and the other men wear? The students don't have them. Do they stand for something, or are they just decoration?"
>
>   His face fell, and his hair fell too, into his eyes as usual. "You don't know? Haven't I told you that?" he demanded.
>
>   I shook my head dumbly. He took a deep breath and shoved the books away from him. He leaned forward, hooking his thumbs under his brown neckring to show it to me.
>
>   "This is a badge of rank, and also a permanent warning. It was placed on me when I became a Magician, and it cannot be removed except at my death, even if I should acquire the rank of Sorcerer, when another would be added."*